# wordpress Admin Menu shows duplicate entry

Tags: wordpress

Hello am working on wordpress plugin and facing an issue while adding links in admin menu, am making a submenue 
but it show duplicate entry.
Top level menu repeats in submenu I dont know why
please help
screen shots attached.
[image: Admin Menu Pic]

[image: My function]

Comment: That is what is meant to happen - try any other menu and you will see the same - eg pages - same action just a different label - you can alter the label if you want

Comment: what you mean @SimonPollard.? 
I cant understand

Comment: If I edit the label, it updates the both

Comment: Look at https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_menu_page/ to see which parameter effects which label - but basically the link is meant to be there, it is not a fault

Comment: Problem not solved yet, i followed the instructions in link but no success

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/Adding_Administration_Menus In situations where a plugin is creating its own top-level menu, the first submenu will normally have the same link title as the top-level menu and hence the link will be duplicated. The duplicate link title can be avoided by calling the add_submenu_page function the first time with the parent_slug and menu_slug parameters being given the same value.

Comment: Thanks @SimonPollard Problem Solved

Comment: Awesome - I will put it as the answer - if you could mark it as such that would be great.

Comment: By default the first submenu item is meant to be a clone of the main menu item, you can however change it.

From: codex.wordpress.org/Adding_Administration_Menus

"In situations where a plugin is creating its own top-level menu, the first submenu will normally have the same link title as the top-level menu and hence the link will be duplicated. The duplicate link title can be avoided by calling the add_submenu_page function the first time with the parent_slug and menu_slug parameters being given the same value."

Comment: The Duplicate Sub-menu Item can be removed using the remove_submenu_page function:

add_menu_page('Page Title', 'Menu Title', 'manage_options', 'menu-slug', 'my_settings_page');

add_submenu_page('menu-slug', 'Sub Page Title', 'Sub Menu Title', 'manage_options', 'sub-menu-slug', 'my_settings_sub_page');

remove_submenu_page('menu-slug', 'menu-slug');
Use:

remove_submenu_page( string $menu_slug, string $submenu_slug );

Note that the sub-menu slug is the same as the top level menu slug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default the first submenu item is meant to be a clone of the main menu item, you can however change it.

From: codex.wordpress.org/Adding_Administration_Menus

> "In situations where a plugin is creating its own top-level menu, the
>   first submenu will normally have the same link title as the top-level
>   menu and hence the link will be duplicated. The duplicate link title
>   can be avoided by calling the add_submenu_page function the first time
>   with the parent_slug and menu_slug parameters being given the same
>   value."

Answer (score 0):

The Duplicate Sub-menu Item can be removed using the remove_submenu_page function:

```
add_menu_page('Page Title', 'Menu Title', 'manage_options', 'menu-slug', 'my_settings_page');

add_submenu_page('menu-slug', 'Sub Page Title', 'Sub Menu Title', 'manage_options', 'sub-menu-slug', 'my_settings_sub_page');

remove_submenu_page('menu-slug', 'menu-slug');
```

Use:

remove_submenu_page( string $menu_slug, string $submenu_slug );

Note that the sub-menu slug is the same as the top level menu slug.

Answer (score 0):

Solution mentioned above didn't work without adding a priority of "1" to my

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'myplugin_add_submenu') 1);
```

This finally solved the issue with duplicated menu item.